# Add -al to verb to make a noun

Tags: parts-of-speech, suffixes, morphology, derivational-morphology

Do you have any examples of nouns that are formed by adding *-al* to a verb?
I can think of one example (*rental*), but would like to have a few more. Thank you for your help!

Comment: By the way, how do you claim to know that the noun "rental" is formed from the verb "rent"?  The word is 700 years old, so its etymology isn't clear.  It could have just as well come from the noun "rent" being made into the adjective "rental," as in "rental property," which then got back-formed into the noun "rental," meaning "rental property."

Comment: Benjamin Harman - That occurred to me, and that's why I'm asking if anyone has any other examples. Barring no more examples, I would then venture to guess that it went from adjective to noun, instead verb to noun.

Comment: Few -_al_ nouns have been created since the nineteen century ("referral" appears to be one), and it is questionable whether the suffix is still productive. Long-established ones include "arrival", "denial", "refusal", "removal", "trial".

Comment: BillJ - Thank you for that information!

Answer (score 3):

There are a fair number of deverbal nouns ending in *-al*: examples include *arrival, disposal, dismissal, denial, betrothal, approval, appraisal, avowal, betrayal, trial.* You can find more examples by looking through the results of this [search on the dictionary aggregator site OneLook for nouns ending in `al`](https://www.onelook.com/?w=*al&posfilter=cn&ssbp=1).

The [Wiktionary entry on the suffix *-al*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-al) points out that in some cases, *-al* nouns coexist with *-tion* or *-sion* nouns from the same verb, as with *proposal* and *proposition.*

#### Describing the verbs that take *-al* as a suffix

A number of linguists have been interested in figuring out rules about which verbs take *-al* as a noun-forming suffix. It has been observed that the noun-forming suffix *-al* only attaches to verbs that are stressed on the final syllable. There are some more complicated conditions that have been hypothesized to apply to the use of this suffix; you can see some discussion in ["Against Phonological Conditioning of WFRs"](https://books.google.com/books?id=lWxAAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA435&lpg=PA436&dq=%22anterior+consonant%22+%22al%22), 1992, by Anna Malicka-Kleparska, or in ["Phonotactic Properties of Morphological Units"](https://books.google.com/books?id=864tGNzqcrIC&pg=PA433&lpg=PA433&dq=%22anterior+consonant%22+%22al%22), by Edmund Gussmann and Bogdan Szymanek, in *Morphologie: Ein Internationales Handbuch Zur Flexion und Wortbildung,* Volume 1.

Malicka-Kleparska, citing Marchand 1969:237, says that *trial* and *rental* ought to be regarded as loaned words, rather than as words that have been formed in accordance with the English derivational system. These two words do not conform to a generalization that says that *-al* attaches only to Latinate verbs with the structure prefix + root (p. 435 in *Phonological Investigations,* edited by Jacek Fisiak and Stanislaw Puppel). According to Malicka-Kleparska's analysis, the stress pattern of *-al* nouns is not a condition on the use of the suffix, but only a predictable result of the morphological structure of the verbs that it attaches to (p. 437).